# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

elementary OS's [3rd moderator election](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:

[image: matigo]

[image: Hasan]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Maccer]

Comment: Thank you for the opportunity to be a more-contributing member of this community 